# i want to get data "createdAt" and "imageURL" for every user but error "Listen at /Users failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied"

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to retrieve data "createdAt" and "imageURL" for every user who has just registered to RecylerView but is having problems with:

> Listen at /Users failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied

```
DatabaseReference databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(REF_USERS);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -10);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH");
String dateSevenDaysAgo = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
Query query = databaseRef.orderByChild(EXTRA_CREATED_AT).startAt(dateSevenDaysAgo);
query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            assert user != null;
            userList.add(user);
            userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

**Firebase Rule**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your security rules grant access to `/Users/$uid` to any logged in user. But your code tries to read from `/Users` directly, and the rules don't provide anyone read access there.

If you want to be able to read data with your current security rules, you need to change your code to read data from a specific user.

If you want to allow your current code to work, you need to allow the user to read the entire `/Users` node, so move the `".read"` rules that you have one level up.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users": {
      ".read": "auth.uid != null",
      "$uid": {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @van Pufflen If I want to be able to read the data with the current security rules, I change the sample code to what it looks like??

Comment: Oof, don't put significant code in comments please as it becomes pretty much unreadable. If you want to be able to read with your current rules, you will need to read the data for a specific user - so use `addValueEventListener` on a specific `/Users/$uid` path.

Comment: @van Pufflen if with my code above can I apply the rule like this?
[link](https://i.ibb.co/wRnfhxL/Screenshot-239.png)

Comment: No. Your code tries to read `/Users`, and those updated rules *also* don't grant access to `/Users`. The only way to be able read from `/Users` directly as you code does is to change the rules in the way I showed in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The google-services.json file needed to be downloaded and added to the app root directory. The error "DatabaseError: Permission denied" no longer appears.

Comment: @phanza I have implemented the google-services.json file, I also implemented Google Sign-in and it was successful